# Ec2 nginx routing and setup

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, deployment, https, routes

I have a react app(port 8080) and a backend node app(port 3001) running on an aws ec2 instance, I have nginx routing port 80 from the load balancer to the port 8080 on local host in nginx, but, my front end cannot connect to the backend with axios(localhost:3001).

I have an instance of node for the front end and back end in the folders client and server respectively.

I've tried connecting with http and https, adding a direct 3001 listener all the way up to the domain/balancer and replacing all the paths to the domain(didn't work and also insecure if it did), I also tried without nginx.

Comment: Were you able to connect your frontend to backend eventually?